# Trennbare Verben und Präpositionen (Wortstellung)

Tags: difference

Im Texte eines Lieds von Rammstein heißt es:

"Wende dein Antlitz ab von mir"

Dazu habe ich zwei Fragen:

1. Könnte man es so umschreiben "Wende dein Antlitz von mir ab"?
2. Falls ja, was wäre der Unterschied in der Bedeutung?

Grund für die Frage ist, ich zögere immer noch bei derartigen Sätzen, wo trennbare Verben (bzw. abwenden) mit Präpositionen (von, mit, auf, usw...) zusammenkommen.

Vielen Dank an alle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @TheAwfulLanguage said, you can write it [both ways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvNAO.gif), but "Wende dein Antlitz von mir ab" sounds more natural.

So, why is it the other way round? As @RalfFriedl assumes it's indeed a question of rhythm and metric.

When looking at the [songtext](http://www.songtexte.com.de/rammstein/b%C3%BCck-dich.html) (or [listening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pg6fgfVZAsY)) you will notice, that it's completely written in [iambs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)). In an iamb an unstressed syllable (x) is followed by a stressed syllable (X).

`Wende dein Antlitz ab von mir`

`x  X   x   X   x   X  x   X`

in contrast to

`Wende dein Antlitz von mir ab`

`x  X  x    X   x   x   X   X`

Although one can argue, that the first version allows some kind of 'natural' [ceasura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesura), which is typical for Rammstein.

And don't forget: As @Olafant wrote in the comments, it wouldn't rhyme the other way round ^^.

Comment: Small correction: The beginning would be X x x X in both cases, because *wende* has the stress on the first syllable - good answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write both

> 1) Wende dein Antlitz ab von mir
>
> 2) Wende dein Antlitz von mir ab

The meaning is always the same, but 1) sounds a bit more old-fashioned (probably intentional), while nowadays you'd rather write 2).

It's just a nuance, but you might argue that 1) somewhat emphasizes more *abwenden* (turn away), while 2) emphasizes *von mir* (from me). Like in 2) it would not be so important for me for you to turn your face away from others, but from me. But it's quite subtle and maybe it played no role for Rammstein.

Actually, you could even say something like *Dein Antlitz wende ab von mir* which sounds even more antiquated, just like [Antlitz](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Antlitz) itself (today you'd rather say *Gesicht*.)

Comment: Also this kind of falls under "künstlerische Freiheit"

Comment: I was kind of saddened by the answer; I mean, I had hoped that number 1 would be more the rule these days. As a non-native it pains me to have to hold the separable part for the last slot in the sentence; sometimes, when speaking, I even forget what I had to use by the time I finish the sentence, lol. But thanks for clarifying that! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1. "Wende dein Antlitz von mir ab" (imperativ) ist die normale Reihenfolge. "Wende dein Antlitz ab von mir" ist ungewöhnlicher, aber nicht falsch.
2. Man könnte darüber spekulieren, ob der Schwerpunkt etwas anders ist. Wenn aber in einem Lied oder einem Gedicht die Reihenfolge anders ist als gewohnt, dann hat das oft damit zu tun, dass es besser zur Melodie passt, oder zum Rhythmus.

Comment: ... oder einfach damit, dass es sich sonst nicht reimt.